# What's the minimal mongodb data file sizes

Tags: mongodb

Using

```
mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 -port 5432 --smallfiles --dbpath . --oplogSize 16
```

Results in 64Megs used per database. Adding

```
--nojournal
```

Reduces the size to 32Megs but the docs say this "will shorten the start up time in some cases, but can cause significant performance penalties during normal operations."

Are these really the minimal starting database sizes for mongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB will pre-allocate around 2/3GB normally: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation unless you use something like `smallfiles` or `nojournal`.

Basically `smallfiles` cuts off the overhead of `0` byte filled files that would normally exist in allocation of new data files which can be very useful for performance, but very destructive for space.

This is best for small databases really, you might find performance problems in high write databases using this method.

### Edit

Realised I didn't answer the question actually :P, Yes with `--smallfiles` and `--nojournal`, I believe that is the smallest it can get.